# What logs exist on an Exchange Hub Server that should be moved off the C:\ drive?

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010, hard-drive, deployment, configuration

I'm trying to move any logs, queues, etc off the default C:\ drive, but am having trouble locating all the various settings.

This gets tougher when you consider diagnostic logging, and everything else.

> Is there a comprehensive list of settings that need to be changed to move all "data" off the C:\ drive and onto a secondary drive?

Comment: are you moving them on to seperate spindles for performance reasons?  How many drives are you moving to?

Comment: It's on VMWare and I'm moving them because I believe it is a best practice to separate OS and data that may grow.

Comment: AFAIK there is no best practice to simply seperate the OS from the application other than for performance reasons.  As there is a related question here (http://serverfault.com/questions/20600/are-there-compelling-reasons-to-separate-boot-and-data-on-a-server-to-increase) I've added more explanations there

Comment: If you have a heavy-usage server you might want to consider moving Event Log to a separate location.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315417/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the location for the smtp receive connector

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpReceive**

Location for smtp send connector

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpSend**

Location for connectivity log

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\Connectivity**

Location for message tracking logs

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\MessageTracking**

Location for the routing logs

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\Routing**

Instructions to configure the location of the logs can be found here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998617.aspx